# Using Android REST API HttpPost sends empty data on Post body

Tags: android, rest

Im trying to send some data via HttpPost but it comes out empty. below if my method and HttpGET part is working good. but when i try to add some data to Post body and send, I get no error and Logcat (+ REST web service on the other side) show Post data was empty.

```
 public void sendPhoto(View v) {
        final String kookojaUrlGet = "http://localhost/getData";
        final String kookojaUrlPost = "http://localhost/postData";
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(kookojaUrlGet));
                    String returnedStuff = EntityUtils.toString(getResponse.getEntity());
                    Log.d("debug","http get returned " + returnedStuff);
                    JSONObject jsonGet = new JSONObject(returnedStuff);
                    int xxxTime = jsonGet.getInt("timestamp");
                    String xxxNone = jsonGet.getString("nonce");
                    String xxxApp = jsonGet.getString("appName");
                    String xxxCID = jsonGet.getString("csrfToken");
                    Log.d("debug","json was " + xxxTime + " " + xxxNone + " " + xxxApp + " " + xxxCID);
                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
                    c.put("_username","xxx@gmail.com");
                    c.put("_password","123");
                    c.put("_timestamp", xxxTime);
                    c.put("_nonce", xxxNone);
                    c.put("_appName", xxxApp);
                    c.put("CID", xxxCID);
                    c.put("body", photoPost);
                    c.put("long", photoLong);
                    c.put("lat", photoLat);
                    StringEntity sendStuff = new StringEntity(c.toString());
                    HttpPost xxxPost = new HttpPost(kookojaUrlPost);
                    xxxPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xxxPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    xxxPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
                    xxxPost.setEntity(sendStuff);
                    HttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(xxxPost);
                    String postText = EntityUtils.toString(postResponse.getEntity());
                    Log.d("debug", "rest post response was " + postText);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you set the content-type header twice, that probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: my bad! i removed that line. it was commented out in my code actually.

Comment: localhost url are unlikely to work unless your server is actually on the device

Comment: In AVD to connect to localhost you need to use url http://10.0.2.2/ instead of http://localhost/

Comment: i have apache web server on my system and testing on a real device, not AVD.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ might be help you.

Comment: it was useful in general but didnt help me on my specific case. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using "List" instead of JSONObject. here is the code:

```
List<NameValuePair> c = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_username", "xxx@gmail.com"));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_password", "123"));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_timestamp", xxxTime2));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_nonce", xxxNone));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_appName", xxxApp));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CID", xxxCID));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", photoPost));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", "4524524524"));
c.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "242452452"));
xxxPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(c));
```